# How to make an empty div take space?

Tags: css, html

This is my 960 grid system case:

```html
<div class="kundregister_grid_full">
    <div class="kundregister_grid_1">ID</div>
    <div class="kundregister_grid_1">Namn</div>
    <div class="kundregister_grid_1">Anv.Namn</div>
    <div class="kundregister_grid_1">Email</div>
    <div class="kundregister_grid_1">Roll</div>
    <div class="kundregister_grid_1">Aktiv</div>
</div>
```

This is my set of divs, used as a table structure.

CSS says following:

```css
.kundregister_grid_1 {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0; 
    text-align: center;
}
.kundregister_grid_1 {
    width: 140px;
}
```

Don't mind the Swedish naming. I want the divs to show even though they have no values.

```html
<div class="kundregister_grid_full">
 <div class="kundregister_grid_1">ID</div>
 <div class="kundregister_grid_1"></div>
 <div class="kundregister_grid_1"></div>
 <div class="kundregister_grid_1">Email</div>
 <div class="kundregister_grid_1">Roll</div>
 <div class="kundregister_grid_1">Aktiv</div>
</div>
```

Like so, in this case there's no 'Namn' and 'Avn.Namn' in the two columns. However when running this in chrome, they are removed, and do no longer push the other divs in the order `float:left`. So if I have categories in same divs above, then the values would be placed under wrong category.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

It works if you remove floating. http://jsbin.com/izoca/2/edit

With floats it only works if there's some content e.g. `&nbsp;`

Comment: Another answer says putting in a min-height will make it work when floated, and certainly in my own case that worked. If that is always true (now, in 2016) then this answer is wrong. You can just add min-height: 1px; to the width: 140px; without the need to either to remove the float or add content.

Comment: Tried `element.text("&nbsp;");` in jQuery and `&nbsp;` appears on the page.

Answer (score 66):

Try adding `&nbsp;` to the empty items.

I don't understand why you're not using a `<table>` here, though? They will do this kind of stuff automatically.

Comment: Agreed. If it's tabular data, use a table - that's what they are for.

Comment: After all this time, people still assume `<table>` == BAD.

Comment: Using `&nbsp;`, as popular solution as it is, can cause issues in some scenarios. Like when you strike-out (`text-decoration: line-through;`) text the stroke will show over `&nbsp;` , whereas what you really want is just a blank div.

Comment: @Pekka웃, it's not always possible to "use tables". I have this same problem ("How to make an empty div take space") for a responsive design where I make a horizontal table into a vertical table when the width is short. *I am already using tables...*

Comment: @ANeves a table will always space the width correctly in this case, though, no? Not sure I follow....

Comment: @Pekka웃 it's a complex scenario, for responsive tables, where table components end up getting `display: block;` instead of ``table-something`. Something a bit similar to this: https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/ (But a bit better, we don't hack the headers in CSS.) (Try making the window width low on this demo: https://css-tricks.com/examples/ResponsiveTables/responsive.php)

Comment: Tables should only be used when you're actually displaying tabular data. They should not be used for layout, though after all this time it's still happening. In particular, nested tables should not be used. That's the whole point of CSS. 

I have a complex design I'm trying to realise in CSS, and I do not want to use tables.

Comment: @Medlock agreed. The OP's case is clearly tabular data, though.

Answer (score 41):

Simply add a zero width space character inside a pseudo element

```css
.class:after {
    content: '\200b';
}
```

Comment: Oooh, I like this idea since it means the user won't accidentally copy-paste it, pseudo-elements being unselectable by default.

Comment: Works only if there is also a (perhaps emtpy) '.class {}' style.

Answer (score 32):

Slight update to @no1cobla answer. This hides the period. This solution works in IE8+.

```css
.class:after
{
    content: '.';
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: If you want to use this as a fallback to work just when you element is empty add something like: `.class:after:empty`

Comment: @Miguel Garrido - I had to use .class:empty:after for that to work.

Answer (score 28):

A simple solution for empty **floated** divs is to add:

- width (or min-width)
- min-height

this way you can keep the float functionality and force it to fill space when empty.

I use this technique in page layout columns, to keep every column in its position even if the other columns are empty.

**Example:**

```css
.left-column
{
   width: 200px;
   min-height: 1px;
   float: left;
}

.right-column
{
    width: 500px;
    min-height: 1px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: `min-height` is the best solution

Comment: The min-height **only** fixes the issue with `width`.  However, it doesn't prevent the div from having zero height. (try setting the div background to see the problem).  Therefore &nbsp; is a more general solution. Also the content: "." fixes the zero height problem.

Comment: A min-height = 1px does not equal 0! it will be 1 px, if you want default height you can simply say min-height = 100px and min width = 100px, the div will always be 100x100 no way it will be 0

Comment: And to use "&nbsp" is very bad practice, what if you have a big website with many files and each file has 10K html lines? if I will follow your approach I will end up putting "&nbsp" inside each in every file!! what a waste of time!? what if you have a user-generated content website? e.g. a user submit empty comment.. based in your solution I have to build a code to check if the comment is empty, then add "&nbsp" (over complicating for no good reason) min-height and min-width is the best solution because I will write it once and wont worry about it again, even if I add more content in future

Answer (score 4):

You can:

**o** set `.kundregister_grid_1` to:

- `width`(or `width-min`) with `height` (or `min-height`)
- or `padding-top`
- or `padding-bottom`
- or `border-top`
- or `border-bottom`

**o** or use *pseudo-elements*: `::before` or `::after` with:

- `{content: "\200B";}`
- or `{content: "."; visibility: hidden;}`

**o** or put `&nbsp;` inside empty element, but this sometimes can bring unexpected effects eg. in combination with `text-decoration: underline;`

Answer (score 3):

This is one way:

```css
.your-selector:empty::after {
    content: ".";
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I recommend `content: "\200b";`for a [zero width space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm). Additional advantage is that the browser will not select this character (e.g. `CTRL+A` `CTRL+C` will still behave the same).

Answer (score 2):

Why not just add "min-width" to your css-class?

Answer (score 2):

works but that is not right way
I think the w
min-height: 1px;

Answer (score 1):

With using the inline-block it will behave as an inline object. so no floats needed to get them next to each other on one line. And indeed as Rito said, floats need a "body", like they need dimensions.

I totally agree with Pekka about using tables. Everybody that build layouts using div's avoid tables like it's a disease. But use them for tabular data! That's what they're ment for. And in your case i think you need them.

BUT if you really really want what you want. There is a CSS hack way. Same as the float hack.

```css
.kundregister_grid_1:after {  content: ".";  }
```

Add that one and you're also set. (Note: does not work in IE, but that is fixable).

Answer (score 1):

If they need to be floated, you could always just set the min-height to 1px so they don't collapse.

Answer (score 0):

it works for me by set div class row and style=display:table-row

Answer (score -1):

In building a custom set of layout tags, I found another answer to this problem.  Provided here is the custom set of tags and their CSS classes.

HTML

```html
<layout-table>
   <layout-header> 
       <layout-column> 1 a</layout-column>
       <layout-column>  </layout-column>
       <layout-column> 3 </layout-column>
       <layout-column> 4 </layout-column>
   </layout-header>
   
   <layout-row> 
       <layout-column> a </layout-column>
       <layout-column> a 1</layout-column>
       <layout-column> a </layout-column>
       <layout-column> a </layout-column>
   </layout-row>

   <layout-footer> 
       <layout-column> 1 </layout-column>
       <layout-column>  </layout-column>
       <layout-column> 3 b</layout-column>
       <layout-column> 4 </layout-column>
   </layout-footer>
</layout-table>
```

CSS

```css
layout-table
{
    display : table;
    clear : both;
    table-layout : fixed;
    width : 100%;
}

layout-table:unresolved
{
    color : red;
    border: 1px blue solid;
    empty-cells : show;
}

layout-header, layout-footer, layout-row 
{
    display : table-row;
    clear : both;   
    empty-cells : show;
    width : 100%;
}

layout-column 
{ 
    display : table-column;
    float : left;
    width : 25%;
    min-width : 25%;
    empty-cells : show;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /* border: 1px solid white; */
    padding : 1px 1px 1px 1px;
}

layout-row:nth-child(even)
{ 
    background-color : lightblue;
}

layout-row:hover 
{ background-color: #f5f5f5 }
```

The key here is the Box-Sizing and Padding.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `display: list-item` to the class