# min height min width not working on cordova

Tags: html, css, cordova

i'm trying cordova and i forget most of all my past knowledge on html and css...but i wanted to create a simple 3 div layout each 33% of height and 100% of width inside a container. here's my html:

```
 <body>
        <div class="container">
              <div class="ctn1">
              <h2>ddd</h2>
              </div>
              <div class="ctn2">
              </div>    
              <div class="ctn3">
              </div>    
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
```

and my css:

```
body{
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;

}

.container{

    height:100%;
    width:100%;

}
.ctn1{
    min-height: 33%;
    min-width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
.ctn2{
    min-height: 33%;
    min-width: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.ctn3{
    min-height: 33%;
    min-width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

the background is showing only with text inside...thanks

Comment: because min-height not working in percentage. try it in pixel or em.

Answer (score 1):

Inheriting height is always a bit tricky in CSS.

You need to give `html` and `body` 100% height and remove their default margins. Also, make sure the default `h2` margin remains inside its container making your containers `overflow: hidden`.

[Here's your updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hrewnaoc/)

Answer (score -1):

If you wants to these divs 33% of width with some height than use this CSS:

```
body{
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;

}

.container{

    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;

}
.ctn1{
    min-height: 200px;
    width: 33%;
    float:left;
    background-color: red;
}
.ctn2{
    min-height: 200px;
    width: 33%;
    float:left;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.ctn3{
    min-height: 200px;
    width: 33%;
    float:left;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: the % is not working and i don't want to set the px since i'm working with cordova and many device size...

Answer (score -2):

The other 2 divs won't show without any content in. If you need them empty try adding in a non-breaking space (answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416454/how-to-make-an-empty-div-take-space))

So your html should look something like this

```
 <body>
    <div class="container">
          <div class="ctn1">
          <h2>ddd</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="ctn2">
          <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
          </div>    
          <div class="ctn3">
          <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
          </div>    
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: This is a hack and doesn't solve the height problem. Also, a div doesn't require content to be visible, there are better ways using CSS.